# Importing Numpy Failes

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, import

Numpy fails to import.

#### Steps to reproduce:

Installed by PIP
Version = `1.19.3` 
Python version = `3.9.1`

OS = `Wndows 10 , Version 2004`

#### Error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'dtype' from partially initialized module 'numpy.core' (most likely due to a circular import) (E:\Coding Projects\CovProbDec\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py)
```

*env is my python venv*

Full Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Coding Projects\CovProbDec\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "E:\Coding Projects\CovProbDec\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import _add_newdocs
  File "E:\Coding Projects\CovProbDec\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.core import dtype
ImportError: cannot import name 'dtype' from partially initialized module 'numpy.core' (most likely due to a circular import) (E:\Coding Projects\CovProbDec\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py)
```

It also brings up this error when using [Sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) as well

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have a file you called `numpy.py` in your workspace ?

Comment: No. I was working only with sklearn and flask

Answer (score 0):

Re-Installing fixed it. As usual